# Android - Switch keeps checked after orientation change

Tags: android

Switch keeps checked after orientation change, even if I set checked false programmatically.

Here is a example code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Switch sw;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sw = (Switch)findViewById(R.id.sw);
        sw.setChecked(false);

        System.out.println(sw.isChecked());
    }    
}
```

The sout prints false, but the switch keeps checked on the interface. This is the switch xml element in layout file:

```
<Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/sw"
    android:checked="false"/>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your checkbox is not checked on `Orientation Change` is that Android fires Activity methods on `Orientation Change` like so:

```
onPause -> onSave -> onStop -> onCreate -> onStart -> onResume
```

If you want `sw.setChecked(false);` to fire on Orientation Change place it in your Activities onResume() function like so:

```
//Other Code Above, i.e. onCreate();
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    // Put your code here...
    sw.setChecked(false);
}
```

There are also other options to prevent a restart of the Activity per this [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ConfigurationChanges) under Configuration Changes

> In some special cases, you may want to bypass restarting of your
>   activity based on one or more types of configuration changes. This is
>   done with the android:configChanges attribute in its manifest. For any
>   types of configuration changes you say that you handle there, you will
>   receive a call to your current activity's
>   onConfigurationChanged(Configuration) method instead of being
>   restarted. If a configuration change involves any that you do not
>   handle, however, the activity will still be restarted and
>   onConfigurationChanged(Configuration) will not be called.
>   restarted.

And Finally another Option via `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` and `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)`:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  savedInstanceState.putBoolean("YourCheckBox", enable);
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

And retrieve it using this method:

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  boolean mychkbox = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("YourCheckBox");
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! I know about the lifecycle, but I was using `onStart()` method instead of `onResume` and it was driving me mad! I was doing right now the second option, but I think that, for my case, it's more reasonable to use the first one.

Comment: Of course, you could always maintain the user selection via the third option as well. The best part is there are a few choices to use depending on implementation.

Answer (score 0):

More generally you probably want to override following so that you can preserve state like this when orientation changes (and activity re-created)

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean(SOME_BOOL_VALUE, boolVar);
}
```

and read it back then in `onCreate` if `savedInstanceState` is set

Comment: Yeah, I was doing the same right now, thanks for your answer! I was thinking about how to do it without using the Bundle too, as Illdapt has explained, and I think that it will be my choice in this case.